# UWP - Command parameters are empty

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, icommand

I'm using `RelayCommand` which is implemented by Microsoft in their `ICommand` [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand?view=winrt-19041). Here is a brief of my code.

**XAML:**

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="YoutubeUrlText"
         PlaceholderText="Insert link from youtube here... "
         FontSize="20" FontStyle="Italic" Width="450" />
<Button x:Name="ConvertButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="20" Content="&#xE751;"
        Grid.Column="1" Height="40"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Foreground="White" BorderBrush="#FF797979" Background="#FF0096FF" 
        Command="{x:Bind urlSearchViewModel._GetVideo(YoutubeUrlText.Text)}"/>
```

**Code behind XAML:**

```cs
    public sealed partial class UrlSearchPage : Page
    {
        public UrlSearchViewModel urlSearchViewModel;
        public UrlSearchPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            urlSearchViewModel = new UrlSearchViewModel();
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel Code:**

```cs
        public RelayCommand _GetVideo(string url)
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => this.getVideo(url));
        }

        private void getVideo(string url)
        {
            try
            {
                FileInfo mp4 = youtubeConverter.DownloadVideoAsync(url, YoutubeConverter.TemporaryFolder).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

For instance, just ignore silly asynchronous part. The problem is `url` is always an empty string so I receive an `Exception` everytime I press the `Button`.

Comment: `CommandParameter="{x:Bind YoutubeUrlText.Text,Mode=OneWay}"`  add this in `Button` and this only `Command="{x:Bind urlSearchViewModel._GetVideo}"`

Comment: @RaoHammas That way will result "property is not found" by Visual Studio. I think you are talking about `Binding` not `x:Bind`. Btw, I have tried and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP - Command parameters are empty

I'm afraid you can't bind command with a method that contains a parameter and  return type is `RelayCommand`. Please refer the following code and edit your command and pass the parameter with `CommandParameter` property.

```
public class UrlSearchViewModel
{

    public ICommand GetVideo
    {
        get
        {
            return new CommadEventHandler<string>((s) => this.getVideo(s));
        }

    }

    private void getVideo(string url)
    {
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}


public class CommadEventHandler<T> : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public Action<T> action;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.action((T)parameter);
    }
    public CommadEventHandler(Action<T> action)
    {
        this.action = action;

    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Grid Background="GreenYellow">
    <TextBox
        x:Name="YoutubeUrlText"
        Width="450"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        FontSize="20"
        FontStyle="Italic"
        PlaceholderText="Insert link from youtube here... "
        />
    <Button
        x:Name="ConvertButton"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Height="40"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Background="#FF0096FF"
        BorderBrush="#FF797979"       
        Command="{x:Bind urlSearchViewModel.GetVideo}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=YoutubeUrlText,Path=Text}"
        Content="&#xE751;"
        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
        FontSize="20"
        Foreground="White"
        />
</Grid>
```