# Which is better to use in UWP applications: Page-Frame or ContentPresenter?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, frame

My project has several views:UserControl and I cant get how navigate between them without breaking MVVM. UWP project has MainPage instead of MainWindow and this confuse me.

I know in WPF better use ContentPresenter-UserControl, but how be in UWP projects? How right override OnLauncher in app.xaml.cs? (and if you have examples with several views and navigate between them (or just examples with crud) send to me please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, we use [Page Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page?view=winrt-22621) and [Frame Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame?view=winrt-22621) for navigation in UWP apps. UserControl is just a control which is not suitable to be displayed as a whole page. I'm not sure what you mean about `override OnLauncher`. If you want to navigate to different page when launching your app, you just need to find the following code and  change the ManiPage to other Page types.

```
 rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
```

For basic navigation, you could refer to: [Implement navigation between two pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages)

Comment: Code-behind in page is like it: 
`private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2), name.Text); }`

Is it a break of the mvvm?

Comment: @JoJo If you want to use MVVM, you need to handle the button click in ViewModel and do the logic in ViewModel

Comment: [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117294/how-does-this-button-click-work-in-wpf-mvvm)
or what do you mean?

Comment: @JoJo Try to check Nico's solution for UWP-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993329/uwp-command-parameters-are-empty. The link you shared is for WPF

Comment: ye, its nice answer, exept it:
For basic navigation, you could refer to: Implement navigation between two pages

Comment: @JoJo That's for basic navigation, which means it doesn't require MVVM. But this document tells how the navigation works inside the UWP app.